# Unexpected behavior accessing keyword list using `ìn`

Tags: phoenix-framework

In my template (`html.eex` file) I'm trying to use a keyword list to pass options. I have:

```
<%= if :layer1 in @buttonCSS do %><%= @buttonCSS[:layer1] %><% end %>
```

Then, I pass values like this where I use my template:

```
<%= render MyProject.ComponentView, "button.html",
    buttonCSS: [layer1: "font-style: italic;"]
%>
```

If I don't use the `if` condition this works.
So, shouldn't `in` work here?

I've tried to just use `layer1` instead of `:layer1` but then I have an error.

PS: Also, why using `.layer1` instead of `[:layer1]` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As keyword lists are just lists, `in` actually checks if the whole key/value pair exists in the list or not:

```
iex(1)> :a in [a: 1]
false
iex(2)> {:a, 1} in [a: 1]
true
```

You should just check if `@buttonCSS[:layer1]` is truthy or not, as a non-existent key would return `nil`, which is falsy:

```
<%= if @buttonCSS[:layer1] do %>
  <%= @buttonCSS[:layer1] %>
<% end %>
```

If you're actually just printing the value inside the `if`, you can skip the `if` and print the value directly as printing `nil` will not print anything:

```
<%= @buttonCSS[:layer1] %>
```

Demo:

```
iex(1)> EEx.eval_string "<%= @buttonCSS[:layer1] %>", assigns: [buttonCSS: [layer1: "foo"]]
"foo"
iex(2)> EEx.eval_string "<%= @buttonCSS[:layer1] %>", assigns: [buttonCSS: []]
""
```

> PS: Also, why using `.layer1` instead of `[:layer1]` doesn't work?

The dot syntax only works for Maps (and for functions in a Module), not for keyword lists. It should work if you have:

```
buttonCSS: %{layer1: "font-style: italic;"}
```

but note that the dot syntax is not identical to `[]`: it throws an error if a key doesn't exist instead of returning `nil`.

Comment: Should I stay with keyword list or use maps instead? Or is it the same in this simple use case?

Comment: It wouldn't matter much in this case. Maps might be faster for large data sets as a lookup in a list is `O(n)` while in a Map it's `O(log(n))`, but I wouldn't worry about that for less than a few dozen entries. If the number of entries can be more than that, I'd benchmark both approaches and then choose.

Answer (score 2):

[in/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Kernel.html#in/2) should be used when looking for an element in a enumerable (using [Enum.member?/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Enum.html#member?/2) under the hood).

```
iex> :foo in [:foo]  
true
iex> :foo in [foo: :bar]
false
```

This will work though since it will return nil if`@buttonCSS[:layer1]` is not set.

```
<%= @buttonCSS[:layer1] %>
```

Comment: Thank you. I accepted Dogcart's answer only because it also answers my PS question.